# Basic SQL Server Cursor

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I need help writing some basic Cursor
I want creating a table with 4/5 columns and insert into the table 1 Mil rows
I am not sure how to write the Cursor that's where I need my help with :/

Answer (score 1):

The task you mention can be done by creating the table and using a simple t-sql procedure to insert the rows, like so - 
DDL for create table -

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);
```

t-sql to populate table -

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < 1000000

insert into persons values(@cnt,'smith','gever','madison','barcelona');
SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
end;
```

Was this what you meant? Cause it ain't a cursor.

Comment: Well, yeah that's what I wanted. but I was told I can also do it with a cursor, is this correct?

Comment: A cursor is usually used to fetch rows, not for writing bulks of data into a table. The advantage of a cursor is by dynamically altering your flow in response to the input coming from the table. You can find plenty of cursor examples in Microsoft's documentation, start with this link - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Comment: @user1743176: you *can* use a cursor - but you really shouldn't. Whenever you can - **avoid** cursors - they're not a good thing in T-SQL